# What happens if I select two numbers $a$ and $b$ where $\log a - \log b$ does not give you $\log(a/b)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

According to the [Second Logarithm Law (link via ChiliMath.com)](https://www.chilimath.com/lessons/advanced-algebra/logarithm-rules/), the logarithm of the ratio of two quantities is the logarithm of the numerator minus the logarithm of the denominator. In order words,
$$\log a - \log b = \log\frac{a}{b}$$

> What happens if I select two numbers $a$ and $b$ where $\log a - \log b$ does not give you $\log(a/b)$? What does this mean?

Comment: technically, you can have *negative* numbers, say `a = -1` and `b = -1` and let use *real* (no complex!) numbers only: `log(a)` and `log(b)` don't exist, when `log(a / b) == 0`

Comment: "In order words, log a - log b = log(a/b). What happens if I select two numbers a and b where log a - log b does not give you log(a/b). What does this mean?" Did you find such an example of a and b? If log(a) and log(b) are well defined, i.e., if a > 0 and b > 0, then log(a) - log(b) = log(a/b) is true, and hence you cannot select two numbers a and b such that this is not true.

Comment: In your link, they also give these conditions: 1) base > 0 and is not 1; 2) log arguments must be positive and real. If you find a and b such that the Quotient Rule does not hold, then at least one of these conditions is not met.

Comment: It means that you did it wrong.

Comment: Thank you all for the feedback

Answer (score 1):

Nothing happens, because you ***cannot*** select two numbers $a,b$ greater than $0$ and *not* get $\log(\frac{a}{b})$.

---

$\log 0$ and $\log x$ (where $x$ is negative) are **not** defined.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback